# How to use AsyncTask to set value back into called activity

Tags: java, android

I have created an async class as follows.

```
 class RetrieveClimateInformation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ClimateInfo> {
      protected ClimateInfo doInBackground(String... cityNames) {
          //Creating ClimateInfo object and returning it.
      }

      protected void onPostExecute(ClimateInfo climateInfo) {

      }
 }
```

I have spawned this task from MainActivity.

In `doInBackground` method I am creating `ClimateInfo` object and returning it. Now in `onPostExecute()` I have to set this object to the `climateInfo` field in MainActivity. How can I do this. I don't have object of MainActivity in Async task.

Answer (score 0):

Either pass a reference to the activity to the ASyncTask by adding a constructor to your class:

```
RetrieveClimateInformation(MainActivity activity) { this.activity = activity }
```

and call the method later in `postExecute` like you stated or nest the class inside your activity class, that way the task will have access to your activity by default.

Answer (score 0):

Having that `ClimateInfo` is most probably non-serializable nor parcelable, you won't be able to use `Intents` to do this and therefore you won't be able to use Broadcasts. I think the easiest way to do this is using a `Handler` to send a `Message` object in which you can include any object that you want. In the `handleMessage` method, you simply cast the `Message.obj` object to `ClimateInfo` and you got it.

Simply declare a `Handler` in your `Activity`, once initialized, declare a method in your `AsyncTask` like `setHandler(Handler activity_handler)` and call it from your `Activity` as soon as you initialize your `AsyncTask`. This way you're passing that reference to your `AsyncTask` extension and whenever you need to send a `Message` to your `Activity`, simply do something like this within your `AsyncTask` class:

```
final Message my_climate = new Message();
my_climate.obj = your_climate_object;

ActivityHandler.send(my_climate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the async class inside your activity

Public class MainActivity extends Activity {
. 
. 
. 
.

Public class myTask extends AsyncTask<>{

}

}

And in your post execute method , you can set the variable from inside the task